# embedding youtube videos in the canvas element HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, youtube

I am developing an application using `Canvas`API of HTML5, 
It involves uploading videos and/or displaying videos from Youtube in the application by the user.

meaning the user could add a Youtube URL which will then be displayed in the canvas application.

Now how Can I embed the video in the canvas application ?

edit: i mean how to add the youtube player, i tried this frame copy from the video element but it was a resource beast.

Comment: Why do you embed youtube videos on canvas, and not embed the youtube player instead?

Comment: 1 st i need the to know the api or the tool, and i have done my search and its all about youtube video in the video element not the canvas, and what i mean is that i want the youtube player